# Unable to use custom domain on localhost using xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, localhost

I want to use a custom domain for my laravel site. I have done the following things but it didn't work

**I have added this in httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
 ##<VirtualHost *:80>

    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/cms/public"
    ##ServerName cms.test

    ##</VirtualHost>
```

**I have added this in hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1 cms.test
```

When I try to browse cms.test it opens xampp homepage like this[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the # before the code to make it work.

Comment: you mean this # 127.0.0.1 cms.test

Comment: Your vhosts code is fully commented, I fully recommend you reading some basic tutorials before diving into this.

Comment: tell me the answer.

Comment: I literally told you, your code is fully commented thus preventing it from execution.

Comment: @sum20156 Have a read of [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/concept-of-comments-in-computer-programming/) - comments in Apache configs are started with the `#` character

Comment: yes, I have fixed it..thank you. it was a silly mistake